# Create.js and Animate CC -> Navigate to a frame in a "Bitmap video"

Tags: javascript, createjs

I am working on what will hopefully be my first create.js project in Animate CC at my current employer.

I am trying to load in a .mp4 into a Bitmap object, using

```
HTML5ElementForVideo = document.createElement('video');
HTML5ElementForVideo.src = 'bridge-animation-resized-794x652.mp4';
HTML5ElementForVideo.autoplay = false;
video = new createjs.Bitmap(HTML5ElementForVideo);
video.x = 110.00;
video.y = 42.5;
stage.addChild(video);
```

..which works okay, and as expected.  In the video, there are a series of steps which we would like the user to be able to go between, using "Previous" and "Next" step buttons.

I assumed that navigation wise, I would be able to use something along the lines of:

```
[video].gotoAndPlay(x)
```

To move to the right frame in the video.  However, this does not seem to work or be supported?  I only seem to be able to play the video or stop it with .play and .pause?

Any suggestions, please?

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The video is not an Animate or CreateJS object - only the Bitmap drawing it to the stage is. Check out the [HTML Video API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) for how to control it. To set the position, use the `currentTime` property to control the video position.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! That makes things a little clearer.  I kind of assumed CreateJS provided all the functionality itself.